# Laravel query builder return daily count of records returning is slow

Tags: php, sql, laravel, query-builder

In my Laravel 8 API I have an endpoint which returns the number of daily records over a given time. I've kept it as simply as I can, and by default am attempting to retreive daily data to build a graph over the past two weeks.

The issue, is that as more data is inserted into the system the slower the query takes, and as a result, today's records has seen over 1 million being added.

I simply need to get a daily count of the number of records between two dates, and right now it's timing out, what do I need to change in my query to improve the efficiency and retrieval of data?

```php
/**
 * Get grouped applications
 */
public function getGroupedApplications($applications, $from, $to)
{

    try {

      // generate empty days between two dates in case no data is available
      $period = CarbonPeriod::create($from, $to);
      $dates = collect($period->toArray())->mapWithKeys(function ($date) {
        return [$date->format('Y-m-d') => [
          'applications' => 0,
          'created_at' => Carbon::parse($date)->endOfDay()
        ]];
      });

      // group data by day
      $applicationDates = $applications->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
        $date = Carbon::parse($item->created_at);
        return $date->format('Y-m-d');
      });

      // add up daily application totals
      $applicationDates = $applicationDates->map(function ($items, $key) {
        $totalApplications = 0;
        foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
          $totalApplications++;
        }
        return [
          'applications' => $totalApplications,
          'created_at' => $items[0]['created_at']
        ];
      });

      $applicationData = $dates->merge($applicationDates);

      // return the data
      return $applicationData;

    } catch (\Exception $e) {

      // return empty array
      return [];

    }

}

/**
 * Get daily application graphs
 */
public function generateGraphsForApplications($from, $to)
{

    $presentable = [
      'from' => $from,
      'to' => $to,
      'summary' => [
        'total_applications' => 0
      ],
      'graphs' => [
        'labels' => [],
        'data' => []
      ],
      'applications' => []
    ];

    try {

      $applicationData = Application::where('created_at', '>=', $from)
                                    ->where('created_at', '<=', $to)
                                    ->get();

      $applications = $this->getGroupedApplications($applicationData, $from, $to);

      foreach ($applications as $key => $application) {
        array_push($presentable['graphs']['labels'], Carbon::parse($application['created_at'])->toISOString());
        array_push($presentable['graphs']['data'], $application['applications']);

        $presentable['summary']['total_applications'] += $application['applications'];
      }

      $presentable['applications'] = $applicationData;
      foreach ($presentable['applications'] as $key => $application) {
        try {
          $presentable['applications'][$key]['data'] = json_decode($application['data']);
        } catch (\Exception $e) { }
      }

      return $presentable;

    } catch (\Exception $e) {

      return $presentable;

    }

}
```

`generateGraphsForApplications` is what we're looking at and is what interfaces with the API route.

Comment: `whereBetween` might be a bit more efficient than doing a double comparison on created_at. You may also need an index on `created_at` to help speed up the query. You might also want to try some timing logging with [microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) to see exactly where the slowdowns are

Comment: Your code is not good, how can it take so many lines to simply: "I simply need to get a daily count of the number of records between two dates" That is basicly Model::whereBetween('date', [now()->subDays(2), now()])->count();

Comment: @mrhn you're mistaken here, `count()` does not give me a day-by-day count of records.

Comment: then do the group by? how can that be that to giant blocks of code you have there?